# Creating dynamic array, adding string content from excel table, expanding array when necessary

Tags: arrays, vba, dynamic

I am making a Sub that creates a dynamic array and goes through a column in excel pulling strings and adding them to the array. However, I do not know how many different words are in the column and I do not want duplicates of the same word in my array. So I made my array get the value of the range it is on, check everything in the array to see if it matches anything and if not it adds the string to the array by expanding the array first before placing it. However, I am not very good at array handling and i am getting an error "Subscript out of range" for this snippet

```
 departments(0) = ActiveCell.Value
```

here is the rest of the code. I will make an example of the column

```
   Sub getDepartments()

  Dim lb As Integer
  Dim ub As Integer
  Dim matches As Boolean

 lb = 0 'lower bound
 ub = 1 'upper bound

 Dim departments() As String  'array of departments

 Range("A2").Select 'starting point for gathering department indexes

 departments(0) = ActiveCell.Value 'setting first value in table to first        index in array

  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'after getting first value, go to the next for comparison

   Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""  'loop through column "A" until you reach the end

      For Each i In departments    'looping through each element in array to compare to the current value of the table

    matches = False

    If i = ActiveCell.Value Then   'if just one of the indexes matches, then we dont need it because we already have it
        matches = True
    Else
        i = i + 1   'keep looping through to find matches.
    End If
Next i

If matches = False Then
    ub = ub + 1
       ReDim Preserve departments(ub)
       departments(ub) = ActiveCell.Value
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
 Loop

  For Each i In departments

    Range("G2").Select
    departments(i) = Range("G2").Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      i = i + 1

     Next i

  End Sub
```

should end with an array containing [Raleigh, Charlotte, Wilmington]
the column looks like this...

Raleigh
Raleigh
Charlotte
Raleigh
Charlotte
Wilmington
Raleigh
Wilmington

Comment: My suggestion is to pull each of the string and add it to a Dictionary. You can check your dictionary object to see if that string has already been added. When you're done with all the strings, simply ReDim your array to `yourDict.Count` and copy the strings over to the new array.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I just started looking into how to use dictionaries and it looks like something that could really help me. Ill attempt to use them in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        On Error Resume Next
        Line=Inp.readline
        Dict.Add Line, ""
        If Err.Number <> 0 then
            If LCase(Arg(1)) = "l" then
                Dict.Remove Line
                Dict.Add Line, ""
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    For Each thing in Dict.Keys()
        Outp.writeline thing
    Next
```

Dictionaries test for unique keys. You don't need to use the values, just the keys.

Above is sample code in VBS.

**DeDup**

```
filter dedup {f|l}
filter dup {f|l}
```

Removes duplicate lines in a file keeping either the first or last occurence

```
f - keeps the first occuring duplicate line
c - keeps the last occuring duplicate line
```

**Example**

```
filter dedup f < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```